# Rewriting a matrix expression

Tags: matrices

In two different books I found different expressions for the same expression. However, I do not fully understand how I can reformulate this expression or rather why this represents exactly the same expression.

$\Sigma(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1}$ and ($\Sigma^{-1}-2tA)$

where $\Sigma$ and $A$ are $k$ by $k$ matrices and $t$ is a scalar.

Comment: Which books? Are $A$ and $\Sigma$ related in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(\Sigma^{-1}-2tA)\left(\Sigma(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1}\right) \\ = \left((\Sigma^{-1}-2tA)\Sigma\right)(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1} \\ = (\Sigma^{-1}\Sigma-2tA\Sigma)(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1} \\ = (I-2tA\Sigma)(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1}\\ =I$$

so they are not the same expression, but one is the inverse of the other (assuming both exist)

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. A short follow-up question in this context: What would be the consequence if we have $(I-2tA\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}$ instead of $\Sigma(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1}$. Would it change anything?

Comment: $(I-2tA\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1} = \Sigma^{-1}-2tA\Sigma\Sigma^{-1}=\Sigma^{-1}-2tA$